# implementing fonts on react native not looking like design

Tags: ios, react-native, styles

the designer sent font definitions from xd.
trying to implement in react native, after changing the style I can see the font changes on the ios simulator but it still does not look like the design.

this is the style code I used:

```
showPasswordText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf',
}
```

[adding a pic to show the differences: the left is the design and the right is the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUrTH.png)

thank you

Comment: can you provide a photo of the font in design and what actually appeared ?

Comment: first fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold', if you are not sure u added the font right ! check that topic https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: i went through this guide again and did everything exactly like they said and it worked! thank you.